# Prevent duplicate records to a table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to prevent duplicate values into a database table from a form using PHP.

I have created the following:

A database with a table named **clients**:

```
CREATE TABLE clients(
 firstName varchar(20),
 lastName varchar(20),
 primary key(firstName, lastName));
```

A simple form named **form.html**

```
<h2>Enter your First and Last Name</h2>
<form action="frm_script.php" method="post">
<p><strong>First Name:</strong><br /> <input type="text" name="firstName" /></p>
<p><strong>Last Name:</strong><br /> <input type="text" name="lastName"/></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Customer" />
</form>
```

A form processing script named **frm_script.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//get the name and comment entered by user
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

//connect to the database
$dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

//insert results from the form input
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO clients(firstName, lastName) VALUES('$firstName', '$lastName')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

mysqli_close($dbc);
}
echo "Customer Added";
?>
```

So far with my **frm_script.php** file the above works and for a unique record displays customer added.  However, for a duplicate record it throws "Error Querying Database".

How can I update the **frm_script.php** script for the following?

If a duplicate row is found on entering a First / Last name combination it should display the message "Client already listed" along with that record.

If no duplicate row is found on entering a First / Last name combination on the form it should insert the entry to the database and display the message "customer added"

I have read that a SELECT should be run first then an INSERT but I am not sure how to implement this into my existing code.

Comment: Replace `die('Error querying database.')` with `die(mysqli_error($dbc));`

Comment: `firstName='); DROP TABLE clients; --`. Bye bye clients.

Comment: Hi Amal, I like your solution.  A nice easy way to see a duplicate entry is causing a problem with inserting the record.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //get the name and comment entered by user
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

    //connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');
    $check=mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from clients where firstname='$firstname' and lastname='$lastname'");
    $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

   if($checkrows>0) {
      echo "customer exists";
   } else {  
    //insert results from the form input
      $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO clients(firstName, lastName) VALUES('$firstName', '$lastName')";

      $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

      mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
    echo "Customer Added";
    };
  ?>
```

just check for rows in your db for firstname and lastname if exists echo- your message else 
 insert

Comment: **Warning:** This answer is wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 4):

Since your primary key is (firstName, lastName), you don't need php to prevent insertion of duplicate values. Mysql does that for you, because primary keys have to be unique. 
(if it was'nt your primary key you could use a unique constraint)

To display your error message "Client already listed" on duplicate entries, you can use `mysqli_errno($dbc)` and check for the error code `1062`. 
Quick fix that should do what you want: replace `or die('Error querying database.');` with 
`or die(mysqli_errno($dbc) == 1062 ? "Client already listed" : 'Error querying database.');`

Answer (score 1):

After you process the `$_POST` data, use a `SELECT` query followed by an `if` statement to check if there are any rows in the table with the same first name and last name as the `$_POST` first name and last name data.

If there is, display a message that this data has already been inserted.

If there isn't, use an `INSERT` query to add this data to the database table, and display a message that this data has been added to the table.

Comment: Hi goddfree, I did just that using the reply from Sai above.Still getting errors though - the first: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters and the second: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null.  I don't know exactly what these mean - any ideas? Thanks ;-)

Comment: `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters` this error means you have not pass the connection or your connection is not establish to data base. `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null` means you query is not working properly. test your query in database first then use it in php as good practice

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem all the time. I've gone from using an auto-incremented primary to using an md5 hash most of the time. So while I haven't implemented this myself yet - no opportunity/need presently - you could do create a primary key (VARCHAR 32) that is an md5 hash of the first and last name. Like this:

```
$key = md5(strtolower($firstName . $lastName));
```

Make the column this key goes into te primary key. Then you use an `INSERT IGNORE` and you can ignore any errors.

Then you run a `SELECT` on the $key to return everything related to `$key`and display any info you have on the user in a friendly format. You don't have to show the user an error at that point, simply provide them with the info already captured. If you are worried about users with the same name seeing each other's data then the data can be obfuscated. For example instead of showing a phone number (333) 444-5555 you show (333) 444-5**5 or (333) ***-5555. Something that gives the user enough info to know if it is them or someone else with the same name.

Typically I've used the `SELECT`, if empty `INSERT` and `SELECT` again, method. And it works but it is significantly slower than a simple `INSERT IGNORE` and then `SELECT`. I use a DAO I've built on top of PDO and the `INSERT IGNORE` works fine when a single column is the primary key. I have not tried it on a primary key based on more than 1 column nor have I tried it with the mysqli_* function.

Comment: Wow gabe, thanks for your thorough answer.  It definitely gives me something to work towards.  Thanks for the response I will have to give it a try ;-)

Comment: @AndyR no problem. When I wrote this I didn't think I would need it but I'm in the middle of it right now. For example, I am capturing all of my AdWords campaigns and their status (Paused, Active, etc). Well typically I would put all the campaigns in one table, the statuses in another, and then create link table - camp2stat. However, the status can change over time and I'd like to store when it changed. So I now have a link table with a date not just the ID for the campaign and the ID for the status. However, I don't want to store the status for every day just when they change...