# how to avoid duplicate records insertion in php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I avoid duplicate records insertion in PHP MYSQLi?
this my script :

```
$nama=$_POST['nama'];
$member=$_POST['member'];
$peserta=$_POST['peserta'];
$tour=$_POST['tour'];

mysqli_query($conn,"insert into gathering (nama, member, peserta, tour) values ('$nama', '$member', '$peserta', '$tour')");

header('location:index.php');
```

Comment: Make column `unique`.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19715966/1839439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will help you inserting unique data:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nama, member, peserta, tour FROM gathering where nama = '$nama' and member = '$member' and peserta='$peserta' and tour='$tour'")
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($total==0)
{
    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into gathering (nama, member, peserta, tour) 
values ('$nama', '$member', '$peserta', '$tour')");
}
```

Comment: If you're just counting the number of rows, why do you need to select all those columns? Just use `SELECT 1 FROM ...`

Answer (score 1):

1.You can alter table with Unique constraint :

```
ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD UNIQUE (columnName);
```

2. get record from table before insert record and check whether record is already exist or not.

   ```
   $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM gathering where (nama = '$nama' )";
   $duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);
   if (mysql_num_rows($duberaw) > 0) {
      show error msg;
   }else{
      mysqli_query($conn,"insert into gathering (nama, member, peserta, tour) values ('$nama', '$member', '$peserta', '$tour')");
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

first check if the row exists and then insert

```
$res= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT 1 from gathering where nama='$nama' and member='$member' and peserta='$peserta' and tour='$tour'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0)
{
mysqli_query($conn,"insert into gathering (nama, member, peserta, tour) values ('$nama', '$member', '$peserta', '$tour')");
}
else
{
echo "record already exists";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a column with primary key

```
ALTER TABLE gathering ADD COLUMN `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST
```